# Slice, projection, contour: A terminology question.

Tags: notation, terminology, definition, transformation, projective-geometry

Consider a multivariate function, say $y=f(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$, and suppose that
$z=f(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_{n-1},g(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_{n-1}))$.

What do we call $z$ with respect to $y$? Projection, level set, contour, slice, shadow etc?

And also what is $y$ with respect to $z$? A parent, hyper, mother, etc function!

What do we call $g$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function given by $z$ is very close to a *restriction* of the function $f$ (the function given by $y$) to the set where $x_n=g(\ldots)$. $f$ is essentially an *extension* of this function.

The reason I say "very close" and "eessentially" is that an actual restriction would have to still take $n$ inputs (even if there were only one allowed $x_n$ for each choice of the other inputs). But I would informally call this case a restriction, too - especially if I were imagining things In terms of a fixed $n$-dimensional space (or $n+1$, for the graphs).